# Show 10 last changes of the object in django admin

Tags: django

How can I add 10 recent changes of the object in the admin change_form.py?

I mean something like TabularInline of LogEntry for every model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `change_view` on your `ModelAdmin` to add the appropriate `LogEntry` items to the view's `extra_context`. Then provide your own change_form.html in yourproject/templates/admin or yourproject/templates/admin/myapp/mymodel to render those items. See [ModelAdmin Methods - Other Methods](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#s-other-methods) and [Overriding Admin Templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#s-overriding-admin-templates)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        # Get LogEntry queryset
        my_context = {
            'log_entries': log_entry_queryset,
        }
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context=my_context)
```